# How to pass JSON in a curl GET request?

Tags: curl

I am trying to test a REST api.

Using any other web browser, I can paste the URL into the address field and gt the desired result:

https://some.company.com/SomeAppAPI?cmd=setSomeData&token=d713cebde464&data={"firstName":"TEST"}

Trying the same using curl:

```
curl 'https://some.company.com/SomeAppAPI?cmd=setSomeData&token=d713cebde464&data={"firstName":"TEST"}'
```

(I have to quote the URL, otherwise bash will take it apart.)

the API comes back with an error message saying:

> data must be json encoded array

How would I properly encode this on the command line or would there be any option to have curl read the JSON from a file, while doing a GET request. I know how to make curl read from a file using a POST request, but the API doesn't seem to support HTTP POST here.

Comment: An array in JSON is written `[...]`.

Comment: So you mean it should read: curl 'https://some.company.com/SomeAppAPI?cmd=setSomeData&token=d713cebde464&data=[{"firstName":"TEST"}]' ? Unfortunately this doesn't work as well.

Comment: And the fun thing: It works as expected using wget.

Comment: Does it work with `curl -g`? `{...}` may trigger the special "brace expansion" that `curl` supports in URLs.